Is there a yum repo for older maven versions?
I need maven 3.6.3 for a project. Of course I could download it from https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/ but I like to do all installs with yum.
As far as I know, I can check availability with
yum --showduplicates list maven 

and then install with
yum install maven-3.6.3

But for that, I do need a repo that actually hosts that version. All public repos I could find didn't have 3.6.3.
I tried using common yum repos and looked whether apache hosted one. Search for this on the internet was made complicated by the fact that maven itself also uses a repository, giving many irrelevant search results.

Why exactly do you need an older version?

good question; maven clean install gives an error with 3.8.X and 3.9.X. Assume for a moment I can't adjust anything in the project I want to build.

Why do you use such an old version of Maven? Use more recent versions..

I don't know what's different; I would expect a minor version increase to be backwards compatible, but the project doesn't build with 3.9 and does with 3.6, what more can I say? Even if I knew the cause, assume I can't alter the project-to-build.

You may want to show the error. It may be something trivial.

Maven version 3.6.3 is EOL (end of life) as of March 30, 2021.
You will need to download a tarball instead:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz

Just extract it to a directory of your choice and add the bin/ directory to your PATH.
Also, since you are using a legacy version specifically, a package manager would be overkill.

Script
You could use a script to automate the process:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Variables
MAVEN_VERSION="3.6.3"
MAVEN_DIR="apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION"
INSTALL_DIR="$HOME/.local/$MAVEN_DIR"
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/$MAVEN_DIR-bin.tar.gz"
SYMLINK_DIR="$HOME/.local/bin"
SYMLINK_NAME="mvn"

# Ensure local bin directory exists
mkdir -p "$SYMLINK_DIR"

# Download and extract Maven if not already installed
if [ ! -d "$INSTALL_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Downloading and extracting Maven $MAVEN_VERSION..."
  wget -q -O - "$DOWNLOAD_URL" | tar -xz -C "$HOME/.local"
else
  echo "Maven $MAVEN_VERSION is already installed."
fi

# Symlink Maven executable if symlink doesn't exist
if [ ! -L "$SYMLINK_DIR/$SYMLINK_NAME" ]; then
  ln -s "$INSTALL_DIR/bin/mvn" "$SYMLINK_DIR/$SYMLINK_NAME"
  echo "Created symlink for Maven."
else
  echo "Symlink for Maven already exists."
fi

# Verify installation
echo "Maven $MAVEN_VERSION has been installed!"
mvn -version


Thanks for the help, but this won't install all dependencies, will it?

@Roel the pre-built binaries do not need any dependencies.
